# res.redirect giving 404 NotFound error even when the route is defined in the router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, express, http-status-code-404

It's just a simple react application which has a login form so I want when the user sends their data after verification the user must be redirected to /home by res.redirect. So I was just checking whether res.redirect works or not, so res.redirect('/home') is giving 404 notfound error, I can't understand why. But when I manually type http://localhost:3000/home in the search bar, the home page opens up

Here's the complete code:

this is my router---->

```
import Homescreen from './Homescreen';
import SignUp from './SignUp';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";

function Home(){
return(
    <div>
        <Router>
            <Routes>
                <Route exact path='/home' element={<Homescreen />} />
                <Route exact path='/login' element={ <SignUp /> }/>
            </Routes>
        </Router>
    </div>
)
}

export default Home;
```

this is my SignUp.jsx---->

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import './SignIn.css';

export default function SignUp() {

  const [data, setData] = useState({
      username: "",
      password: "",
  })
  
  const handleinp = (e)=>{
      const name = e.target.name;
      const value = e.target.value;
  
      setData((prev)=>{
        return {...prev, [name]:value};
      });
  }

  function handlesubmit(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log("submit button clicked")
      
      fetch("/SignIn", {
        method: "POST",
        headers:{"Content-Type": "application/json"},
        body: JSON.stringify({username: data.username, password: data.password}),
      } ).catch((err)=>{
        console.log(err)
      })}

  return (
      <div>
          <div style={{backgroundImage: `url("https://assets.nflxext.com/ffe/siteui/vlv3/b85863b0-0609-4dba-8fe8-d0370b25b9ee/fdf508c8-97d0-42fd-a6f9-9bef6bf96934/IN-en-20230731-popsignuptwoweeks-perspective_alpha_website_large.jpg")`, width: "100vw", height: "100vh", backgroundSize: "cover"}}>
              
              <div className='login-content'>
                  <div className='sign-navbar'>
                      <h1 className='login-title'>FlimFair</h1>
                  </div>

                  <form className='inp-form ' >
                  <div className='inp b'>
                      <div className='inp-box'>
                        
                          <h1 className='inp-title'>Sign In</h1>
                          <input className='inp-text' type='email' placeholder='Enter Email' name='username' value={data.username} onChange={handleinp} required/>
                          
                          <input className='inp-text' type='password' placeholder='Password' name='password' value={data.password} onChange={handleinp} required/>
                          
                          <button className='inp-submit' type='submit' onClick={(e)=>handlesubmit(e)}>Submit</button>
                      </div>
                      
                      <h1 style={{color: "#d1a0a0", fontWeight: "500", marginTop: "7rem", fontSize: "1.8rem"}}>New to FlimFare? <a href='/' style={{textDecoration: "none"}}>Sign Up now</a></h1>
                      <h1 style={{color: "#d1a0a0", fontWeight: "500", fontSize: "1.5rem", margin: "2rem 0 3rem 0"}}>This page is protected by Google reCAPTCHA to ensure you're not a bot.</h1>
                  </div>
                  </form>

              </div>

          </div>
        
      </div>
  )
}
```

this is my server.js---->

```
const express = require("express");
require('./connect');
const cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const expressSession = require("express-session");

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:false}));
app.use(require('body-parser').text({type: '*/*'}));
app.use(expressSession({secret: "secret", resave: false, saveUninitialized:false}));


app.post("/SignIn", async(req, res)=>{
    console.log(req.body);
    res.redirect('/home')
})


app.listen(port, ()=>{
    console.log(`Server running successfully on port no. ${port}`);
})
```

the server correctly logs the incoming data

this is the error I am getting---->

```
SignUp.jsx:24 
GET http://localhost:3000/home 404 (Not Found)
```

Tried to find solutions from ChatGPT, Google, YouTube but nothing worked

Comment: This happens because of you are mixing server side code with client side code. You are trying to redirect the user via `res.redirect('/home')` on the server side to the route `/home` but there is no route `/home` registered on the server side. What you actually want is to redirect the user on your client side to `/home`.  I think you are looking for the `useNavigation` hook of `react-router-dom`: https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-navigate .
Use this hook in your `SignUp.jsx` component and redirect the user after your `fetch('/SignIn',...)` gots resolved.